# GitHub API not creating files

Tags: java, git, api, http, github

Basically what the title says. I’m trying to use the GitHub API to create a file using java, but I don’t know why it’s not working.

Code:

```
val url = URL("https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repo-name>/contents/content.txt")
val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
connection.doOutput = true
connection.requestMethod = "PUT"
val os = connection.outputStream
val osw = OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8")
osw.write("{\"content\":\"content\",\"message\":\"added content\"}")
osw.flush()
osw.close()
os.close()
connection.connect()
```

Comment: Check the response to see if you're getting an error code.

Comment: I don't know anything about the GitHub API, but I don't see any authentication in your code example, which I would guess is probably required.

Comment: @Slaw Response just says "Not Found"

Comment: Then I only have two guesses: (1) Like @xdhmoore mentioned, uploading a file probably requires authentication but you don't seem to provide any, and (2) according to [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents) the "content" is supposed to be Base64 encoded.

Comment: Just a sanity check: are you replacing `<username>` and `<repo-name>` with the appropriate values? [These appear to be the authentication docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods)